# Point cloud is decreasing when adding in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, point-cloud

I have a point cloud with coordinate information from Agisoft metashape software and I make the point clouds into the WGS84 coordinate system at Agisoft. But when I try to use the point cloud in QGIS software, the point clouds are decreasing, not the same as in Agisoft.

In QGIS I also set into the WGS84 coordinate system. Is there anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please describe the issue with more details? What do you mean with "the point clouds is decreasing" exactly?

Comment: "decreasing"? What does that mean?